# acme-challenge conflict with TXT record

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, cert-manager, fastly

I'm using cert-manager on Kubernetes and I'm trying to use the acme-challenge for creating a wildcard certificate on our Kubernetes cluster using DNS solver, in my case it seems that Fastly already uses the acme-challenge TXT record.
there are two solutions that I can think of but I'm not sure it's possible and I'd like to find more ideas and find out what is the best solution to resolve the issue.

- Provide Fastly with the ACME account private key, in this case Fastly and cert-manager will use the same value of a acme TXT record - https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/#reusing-an-acme-account, https://medium.com/quark-works/kubernetes-same-domain-ssl-with-dns-verification-using-lets-encrypt-e3e806644bf4
- Use some other method on Fastly in order to validate ownership of the domains and generate a wildcard certificate
- can I use the acme-challenge TXT record as a sub subdomain?

Comment: Here is another example of the same issue https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/multiple-acme-challenge-and-cnames/183097

Comment: I work at Fastly and I reached out to our TLS support team and their had a few questions about your setup. The feedback loop on StackOverflow isn't ideal. Would be great if you could reach out to support@fastly and the team can help investigate for you.

Comment: @Integralist, sure, I'll do that, thank you